# How to configure Python so that I can import a function directly from package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

Suppose I have a package structure like

```
pkg
   __init__.py
   module
      __init__.py
      a.py
      b.py
```

Suppose, there is a function *func* in a.py. I want to create a library, that can import *func* directly from pkg.

`from pkg import func`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this via the `__init__.py`.

**`pkg/__init__.py`**

```
from .module.a import func
```

That way when `pkg` is accessed, the `__init__.py` would be loaded thus allowing direct access to `pkg.func`

This is as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages):

> A regular package is typically implemented as a directory containing an `__init__.py` file. When a regular package is imported, this `__init__.py` file is implicitly executed, **and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace.** The `__init__.py` file can contain the same Python code that any other module can contain, and Python will add some additional attributes to the module when it is imported.